# Regex: Parsing html tag links

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex

I want to make a PARSING by replacing `pagina-EN` with `aborde.html` . I want this replace to be make with Regex, not the normal find/replace way.

So I have:

`<link rel="canonical" href="https://MyWebsite.com/en/aborde.html" />`

and down another html tags:

`<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://MyWebsite.com/en/pagina-EN.html" />`

`<link rel="alternate" hreflang="sl" href="https://MyWebsite.com/sl/pagina-EN.html" />`

`<link rel="alternate" hreflang="bg" href="https://MyWebsite.com/bg/pagina-EN.html" />`

`<link rel="alternate" hreflang="sk" href="https://MyWebsite.com/sk/pagina-EN.html" />`

`<link rel="alternate" hreflang="uk" href="https://MyWebsite.com/uk/pagina-EN.html" />`

**The output should be:**

`<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://MyWebsite.com/en/aborde.html" />`

`<link rel="alternate" hreflang="sl" href="https://MyWebsite.com/sl/aborde.html" />`

`<link rel="alternate" hreflang="bg" href="https://MyWebsite.com/bg/aborde.html" />`

`<link rel="alternate" hreflang="sk" href="https://MyWebsite.com/sk/aborde.html" />`

`<link rel="alternate" hreflang="uk" href="https://MyWebsite.com/uk/aborde.html" />`

**My solution:**

Search: `(?s)<link rel="canonical" href="(.*?)" />.*?<link rel="alternate" hreflang=".*?".*?\K href="(.*?)//(.*?)/(.*?) />`

Replace By:  `\thref="\1" />`

- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Comment: @Toto, maybe you can have an opinion?

Comment: How about simply doing: Find: `pagina-EN.html` ; Replace: `aborde.html` ? Or am I missing something?

Comment: it would have been very easy. But I have 1500 files, and the links are different :) So I have to search a pattern so as to make replacement in all those files..

Comment: anyway, my solution works. Except that I use on replacement `\t` instead of `\x20` because  `\x20` doesn't work. Don't know why...